# Using multicast with Zerotier

Tags: multicast, zerotier

I'm trying to join a multicast group (I think this is why multicast isn't working, but I'm new to it).

So I'm trying:
`sudo ip maddr add 239.255.1.1 dev ztxxxxxxx`

But that doesn't seem to work, in that `ip maddr` doesn't show it against the ZT interface. It does, however, show it against eth0, which I think is an issue?

```
2:  eth0
link  33:33:00:00:00:01
link  01:00:5e:00:00:01
link  33:33:ff:97:c0:4c
link  33:33:00:00:00:fb
link  01:00:5e:00:00:fb
link  01:00:5e:7f:01:01
inet  239.255.1.1 users 2
inet  224.0.0.251
inet  224.0.0.1
```

So, then I'm trying to remove it from eth0 with `sudo ip maddr del 239.255.1.1 dev eth0` but I get:

```
ioctl: No such file or directory
```

Is it me?